# cshtml How can i hide a specific div based on a condition? (without using styles)

Tags: html, css, razor

so i have 2 divs

```
<div id="@components">
Test
</div>

<div id="@documents">
if(documents.count > 0){
then hide div id components 
}
</div>
```

So essentially what I'm looking to do is hide the "components" div within the code of the "documents" div. I know i can set the display:none in styles but how would i hide the div for components directly?

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.document.getElementById("@components")` to get your `@component div` anywhere on the page and then you can do what you want with it.

```
<div id="@components">
Test
</div>

<div id="@documents">
if(documents.count > 0){
    //then hide div id components
    let componentsDiv = window.document.getElementById("@components");
    if(componentsDiv)
        componentsDiv.style.display = "none";
}
</div>
```